# data not saving in custom table from observer in magento?

Tags: magento, events, magento-1.8

I am working on magento 1.9 version.
I have created a event and observer as below-

```
<events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <autosuggest_catalog>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>autosuggest/observer</class>
                    <method>checkData</method>
                </autosuggest_catalog>
            </observers>        
        </catalog_product_save_after>           
    </events>
```

But it not save data in my custom table.

```
public function checkData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {   
    $model = Mage::getModel('autosuggest/autosuggest');
    $model->setEntityId(5);
    $model->save();
}
```

Observer calls on product save after but saving my value in db.
I have following table-

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('autosuggest')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('autosuggest')} (
 `autosuggest_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 `content` text NOT NULL default '',
 `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
 `created_time` datetime NULL,
 `update_time` datetime NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`autosuggest_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Please give some guidance regarding this.

Comment: put config.xml for check module declaration and table..

Comment: Are you trying to update a row or create a new one? Also, I see you are trying to save the data to entity_id which I don't see in your table?